# ALTER DATABASE rejected

Tags: mysql

I installed the mysql-server from the official mysql docker hub https://hub.docker.com/r/mysql/mysql-server/.

Now i'm trying to alter the collate and charset of my default created database 'mysql' with the code:

> ALTER DATABASE mysql CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;

And i'm getting the error:

> Error Code: 3552
>   Access to system schema 'mysql' is rejected.

What can I do in order to change the charset and collate of this database?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Mysql versions is 8.0.12.

Edit2: running docker with the command:

> docker run --name test-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=###### -e MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=% -p 3306:3306 -d mysql/mysql-s erver:latest

Comment: You need to be root

Comment: I'm indeed logged as root.

Comment: Get rid of mysql from the command if you're already logged onto the mysql server as root. Unless the db name is mysql?

Comment: The database name is mysql. Is a default created database. Already have all granted permissions.

Comment: "What can I do in order to change the charset and collate of this database?" **You can't** lucky for you MySQL didn't do it because you can get trouble if you change the mysql default database charset